# swift generics: how to pass data to target instance variable

Tags: swift, generics

Take this code:

```
func openStoryboardWithName<T: UIViewController>(name: String, asType type: T.Type) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: name, bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! T
    controller.title = "test"
    controller.someProperty = "some value"
    presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Error:

> Value of type 'T' has no member 'someProperty'

Obviously I know that it has, but how can I write to it (or test if it exists)?

Comment: hehe, that downcast to `UIViewController`. `UIViewcontroller` has no attribute `someProperty`

Comment: I would make that method work for `UIViewController` in general. And do the specific stuff in the subclass itself. Much more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that `T` has `someProperty` then you need to tell the compiler about that somehow.  One of the ways to do so is to use a constraint like this:

```
protocol HasSomeProperty: class {
    var someProperty: String { get set }
}

func openStoryboardWithName<T: UIViewController where T: HasSomeProperty >(name: String, asType type: T.Type) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: name, bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! T
    controller.title = "test"
    controller.someProperty = "some value"
    presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Another way is subclass `UIViewController` and use the sub-class in your method:

```
class UIViewControllerThatHasSomeProperty: UIViewController {
    var someProperty = ""
}

func openStoryboardWithName<T: UIViewControllerThatHasSomeProperty>(name: String, asType type: T.Type) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: name, bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! T
    controller.title = "test"
    controller.someProperty = "some value"
    presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: The protocol works just fine! Maybe the error I am getting is unrelated, but if I call that function e.g. with `openStoryboardWithName("test", asType: MyTVC)` (where `MyTVC` is a UITableViewController) I get the error: Generic Parameter 'T' could not be inferred. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Pieter, I would need to see more code around that place.

Comment: I cannot post long code in the comments apparently. Posted a demo piece on pastie: http://pastie.org/10619081#